# How do I take input into variable , from leader key, and execute into a command in vim?

Tags: vim

The result that I want is to find tags by doing leader key+t+word.

```
noremap <leader>t :call someFunc(mystring-after-t)<cr>

function getTag(string)

        execute "normal! :tag " . string "\<cr>"

endfunction
```

Comment: Read `:h input()`. Although in this case it's more natural simply to map it to `:tag<space>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware whether is a way to tell a mapping to take some user input. But you could achieve this as follows (I took the liberty to simplify the task at hand a bit for my convenience...)

```
function EchoWord(x)
  redraw
  echom  'I got the input: ' . a:x 
endfunction

noremap <leader>l :call EchoWord(input(""))<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, I think that would work or is the closest that I'm going to get. I added execute to make it work. ```execute "tag " a:x```